# Tool to replace block in a file

Tags: text-processing, scripting, configuration, utilities

Most configuration management software tools have a way to replace a block in a file.

Example:

- SaltStack: [blockreplace](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.blockreplace)
- Ansible: [blockinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/blockinfile_module.html)

I want exactly this, but without the overhead of these big tools.

Is there a simple tool to update an maintain a block in text file?

Example: I want to update `/etc/some-server/some-server.conf`

I want to insert/update a block like this:

```
## start my-block
key1=value1
key2=value2
## end my-block
```

I know that I can do this with some lines of awk or python, but I search a ready to use tool.

Comment: Ansible is hardly "big".  It doesn't require any server or other infrastructure.  Why not just use it since it does what you want?

Comment: @larsks ... ok that's a good reason for ansible.

Answer (score 0):

Sed is good for text replacement. I'm not near a bash shell to test this but roughly speaking the command you need/have readily available given my limited knowledge of your problem is

```
sed '/in lines containing this/cut this/paste this/' in.file >out.file
```

It also takes a substitute 's/this/that/' format and ideal in a series of piped commands

Answer (score 0):

How simple this is depends on how the tool should behave in non-nominal conditions. If there's always exactly one block in the file with the special comments, it's easy enough with awk, for example.

```
awk '
    /^## end my-block$/ {skip=0}
    !skip {print}
    /^## start my-block$/ {skip=1; system("cat new-block-content") || exit(1)}
' </etc/some-server/some-server.conf >/etc/some-server/some-server.conf.new &&
mv /etc/some-server/some-server.conf.new /etc/some-server/some-server.conf
```

If you want to add the block at the end if not already present, it's still not too hard:

```
awk '
    /^## end my-block$/ {skip=0}
    !skip {print}
    /^## start my-block$/ {skip=1; system("cat new-block-content") || exit(1)}
    END {print "## start my-block"; system("cat new-block-content") || exit(1); print "## end my-block"}
' </etc/some-server/some-server.conf >/etc/some-server/some-server.conf.new &&
mv /etc/some-server/some-server.conf.new /etc/some-server/some-server.conf
```

Coping with other scenarios (e.g. start comment present but not end comment, multiple blocks, …) gets progressively more difficult.